# how to insert multiple values in one field?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a query:

```
    INSERT
INTO I#journal
  (
    Type_,
    Mndnr,
    Obj,
    Status,
    Reason
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'PO',
    '0177',
    '000222',
    'NEW',
    '1'
  )
```

this one works OK.
But instead of '1' I want to insert multiple values in one field, like '1','2','3'

And usually you do it like this:

```
INSERT
INTO I#journal
  (
    Type_,
    Mndnr,
    Obj,
    Status,
    Reason
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'PO',
    '0177',
    '000222e',
    'NEW',
    '1,2,3'
  )
```

But how to do it if values will put there as `'1','2','3'`?

```
INSERT
INTO I#journal
  (
    Type_,
    Mndnr,
    Obj,
    Status,
    Reason
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'PO',
    '0177',
    '000222e',
    'NEW',
    '1','2','3'
  )
```

So, we **can't** change `'1','2','3'` (due of some automation) but we can add anything before and past this string. In result information in `Reason` field should be something like `1,2,3`

How to do that?

Comment: You have to use escape characters.

Comment: Do you mean that you get `'1','2','3'` and you want to insert `'1,2,3'` ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade yes, sorry, I've just fixed the question. So I will have `'1','2','3'` but I want insert those as literal on one field `"1,2,3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT
INTO I#journal
  (
    Type_,
    Mndnr,
    Obj,
    Status,
    Reason
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'PO',
    '0177',
    '000222e',
    'NEW',
    replace(q'['1','2','3']', q'[',']', '')  )
```

Comment: thanks! Almost! I got the string as `'123'` but it should be some separation like `1,2,3`

Comment: changed to `replace(q'['1','2','3']', q'[',']', ',')` it's perfect now!

Answer (score 2):

Insert value `replace(q'$'1','2','3'$', '''', '')`
Single quotes(`'`) is the escape character.
i.e.

```
INSERT
INTO I#journal
  (
    Type_,
    Mndnr,
    Obj,
    Status,
    Reason
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'PO',
    '0177',
    '000222',
    'NEW',
    replace(q'$'1','2','3'$', '''', '')
  );
```

Comment: thanks! But I can't do that. As these values goes there as `'1','2','3'` automatically and I can change anything before and after that string, but can't change the string itsef

Comment: How about replacing a single quotes with double single quotes?

Comment: like this? `"'1','2','3'"` doesn't work. `Error at Command Line:16 Column:5
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00984: употребление столбца здесь недопустимо
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"`

Answer (score 0):

try this  **INSERT**.

```
INTO I#journal
  (
    Type_,
    Mndnr,
    Obj,
    Status,
    Reason
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'PO',
    '0177',
    '000222',
    'NEW',
    '1'
  ),(
    'PO',
    '0177',
    '000222e',
    'NEW',
    '1,2,3'
  )
```

Comment: it says:

`Error at Command Line:18 Column:3
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: неверное завершение SQL-предложения
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO I#journal
 (
   Type_,
   Mndnr,
   Obj,
   Status,
   Reason
 )
 VALUES
 (
   'PO',
   '0177',
   '000222',
   'NEW',
   '''1'',''2'',''3'''
 )
```

Comment: This would appear to work, but could you explain why this would work?